# Como solucionar Warning; undefined array key en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy presentando este error en mi codigo al hacer var_dump me arroja ese warning, le dejo captura y el codigo. El codigo continua de esta forma y al hacer los llamados correspondiente no se muestran en la bd, en las tablas productos, clientes, stock y ventas. Agrego mas codigo para q se pueda observar en q parte estoy fallando y como continuar sin q se presente algun error al ejecutarse. Ya segui la recomendacion de quitar $listaProductos y me arroja una respuesta sin warning, ahora lo q debo hacer es o dejarla para q sea enviada la informacion o quitarla y trabajar de esa forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo

CREAR VENTA

```
    static public function ctrCrearVenta(){

        if(isset($_POST["nuevaVenta"])){

            /* ACTUALIZAR LAS COMPRAS DEL CLIENTE Y REDUCIR EL STOCK Y AUMENTAR LAS VENTAS DE LOS PRODUCTOS*/

            $listaProductos = json_decode($_POST["listaProductos"], true);

                var_dump($listaProductos);

            }

        }

    }
```

LISTAR TODOS LOS PRODUCTOS

```
function listarProductos(){

  var listaProductos = [];

  var descripcion = $(".nuevaDescripcionProducto");

  var cantidad = $(".nuevaCantidadProducto");

  var precio = $(".nuevoPrecioProducto");

  for(var i = 0; i < descripcion.length; i++){

    listaProductos.push({ "id" : $(descripcion[i]).attr("idProducto"), 
                          "descripcion" : $(descripcion[i]).val(),
                          "cantidad" : $(cantidad[i]).val(),
                          "stock" : $(cantidad[i]).attr("nuevoStock"),
                          "precio" : $(precio[i]).attr("precioReal"),
                          "total" : $(precio[i]).val()})

  }

  $("#listaProductos").val(JSON.stringify(listaProductos)); 

}
```

LISTAR MÉTODO DE PAGO

```
function listarMetodos(){

  var listaMetodos = "";

  if($("#nuevoMetodoPago").val() == "Efectivo"){

      $("#listaMetodoPago").val("Efectivo");

    }else{

      $("#listaMetodoPago").val($("#nuevoMetodoPago").val()+"-"+$("#nuevoCodigoTransaccion").val());

    }

}
```

static public function ctrCrearVenta(){

```
    if(isset($_POST["nuevaVenta"])){

        /*=============================================
        ACTUALIZAR LAS COMPRAS DEL CLIENTE Y REDUCIR EL STOCK Y AUMENTAR LAS VENTAS DE LOS PRODUCTOS
        =============================================*/

        $listaProductos = json_decode($_POST["listaProductos"], true);

        $totalProductosComprados = array();

        foreach ($listaProductos as $key => $value) {

           array_push($totalProductosComprados, $value["cantidad"]);
            
           $tablaProductos = "productos";

            $item = "id";
            $valor = $value["id"];

            $traerProducto = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos($tablaProductos, $item, $valor);

            $item1a = "ventas";
            $valor1a = $value["cantidad"] + $traerProducto["ventas"];

            $nuevasVentas = ModeloProductos::mdlActualizarProducto($tablaProductos, $item1a, $valor1a, $valor);

            $item1b = "stock";
            $valor1b = $value["stock"];

            $nuevoStock = ModeloProductos::mdlActualizarProducto($tablaProductos, $item1b, $valor1b, $valor);

        }

        $tablaClientes = "clientes";

        $item = "id";
        $valor = $_POST["seleccionarCliente"];

        $traerCliente = ModeloClientes::mdlMostrarClientes($tablaClientes, $item, $valor);

        $item1a = "compras";
        $valor1a = array_sum($totalProductosComprados) + $traerCliente["compras"];

        $comprasCliente = ModeloClientes::mdlActualizarCliente($tablaClientes, $item1a, $valor1a, $valor);

        $item1b = "ultima_compra";

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

        $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
        $hora = date('H:i:s');
        $valor1b = $fecha.' '.$hora;

        $fechaCliente = ModeloClientes::mdlActualizarCliente($tablaClientes, $item1b, $valor1b, $valor);
```

Comment: el error dice que este dato no existe: $_POST["listaProductos"]

Comment: a pesar que lees un campo con ese id y que usas variables en javascript con esa nombre... en realidad el array/json que envias al backend no tiene ese indice declarado... puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST)` y podras comprobar que estructura realmente viene ...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo q me dices y ahora me arroja este mensaje

Warning: Undefined array key "listaProductos" in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\controladores\ventas.controlador.php on line 25
array(14) { ["nuevoVendedor"]=> string(14) " Administrador" ["idVendedor"]=> string(1) "1" ["nuevaVenta"]=> string(6) "000001" ["seleccionarCliente"]=> string(2) "13" ["agregarProducto"]=> string(10) "Steprising" ["nuevaCantidadProducto"]=> string(1) "1" ["nuevoPrecioProducto"]=> string(5) "35.00" ["nuevoImpuestoVenta"]=> string(1) "4" ["nuevoPrecioImpuesto"]=> string(17) "5.656000000000001"...

Comment: a ver no estas haciendo lo que te dije, esto: `var_dump($_POST)` no es igual a esto: `var_dump($_POST['listaProductos'])` son dos cosas totalmente diferentes...

Comment: la seguna siempre te dara ese warning ... por que ese dato no esta llegando al php

Comment: listo, haciendo eso exactamente me aparce esto: array(14) { ["nuevoVendedor"]=> string(14) " Administrador" ["idVendedor"]=> string(1) "1" ["nuevaVenta"]=> string(6) "000001" ["seleccionarCliente"]=> string(2) "13" ["agregarProducto"]=> string(10) "Steprising" ["nuevaCantidadProducto"]=> string(1) "1" ["nuevoPrecioProducto"]=> string(5) "35.00" ["nuevoImpuestoVenta"]=> string(1) "4" ["nuevoPrecioImpuesto"]=> string(17)...
Debo quitar entonces  esto: $listaProductos = json_decode($_POST["listaProductos"], true);

Comment: no es quitar por quitar... si lo ocupas debes hacer que llegue esa informacion...

Comment: si no lo ocupas entonces quitalo y trabaja con la info que si llega.

Comment: voy a intentar trabajar sin esa parte, porq de verdad me ha costado mucho hacer q llegue la informacion, como podras notar soy nuevo en esto y estoy desde ayer tratando de corregir pero no lo habia logrado hasta q tuviste la amabilidad de darme esa opcion, de igual forma voy a seguir  intentado hacer q llegue la informacion porq hasta ahora no he encontrado o no se como hacerlo, muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder y dar soluciones

Comment: lo que no etiendo es que esperas o que debe llegar dentro de $_POST['listaProductos'] a lo mejor hace falta un poco mas de codigo... pero no has dado una descripcion de que se supone que debe suceder... el error es evidente ...

Comment: el codigo continua de esta forma y al hacer los llamados correspondiente no se muestran en la bd, por eso voy a probaa quitando esa linea, te muestro parte del codigo q sigue: $listaProductos = json_decode($_POST["listaProductos"], true);

   $totalProductosComprados = array();

   foreach ($listaProductos as $key => $value) {

      array_push($totalProductosComprados, $value["cantidad"]);
    
      $tablaProductos = "productos";

       $item = "id";
       $valor = $value["id"];

       $traerProducto = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos($tablaProductos, $item, $valor);

Comment: todo ese codigo que estas poniendo en los comentarios debes ponerlo en la publicacion, editala y agregalo.